# Must be declared scalar value "@iD_User

Tags: c#, mysql, scalar

```
`ql = "select ID from Users where Username = '" + txtusername.Text + "';";
                                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);                                       
                                    Sel_Menu.con.Open();
                                    IDD = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); //here I get int32
                                    Sel_Menu.con.Close();
                                                                        IDD = 15;
                                    sql = "insert into Action_Log ([ID_User],[Action_NR],[AtWhatTime]) values (@iDUser,@action_NR,getdate())";
                                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iDUser", IDD+1-1);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action_NR", 1);
                                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);
                                    Sel_Menu.con.Open();
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //done also with cmd.ExecuteScalar(); ...
                                    Sel_Menu.con.Close();`
```

How can I fix this?
still I have "Must be declared scalar value "@iD_User"" error - everything I do - does not change this error - even not to any other error.

Comment: You instantiate a new SqlCommand after adding your parameters. So obviously your command doesn't have your parameters anymore.

Comment: just to make @Ksven happy: *please please please* parameterize that `txtusername.Text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the line that reinitialize the SqlCommand before the declarations of the parameters

```
  cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iD_User",IDD); 
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action_NR", 1);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atWhatTime","getdate()");
```

You code is adding the parameters to the previous instance of cmd not to the actually executed command. Notice also that the method SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, SqlDbType, int) means, add a parameter with name, type and SIZE. But it doesn't set the value for the parameter.

There is another error. The getDate() function is a T-SQL function. As you are writing it you are passing the string `"getDate()"` to your last parameter. Move it directly in the Sql command text and remove the third parameter.

```
sql = @"insert into Action_Log (ID_User,Action_NR,AtWhatTime) values  
                                (@iD_User,@action_NR,getDate())";
```

Last but not least. In this query you use a parameterized approach (good), while the first one use a string concatenation (bad). Use always parameters to avoid Sql Injection and parsing problems.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't noticed this mistake :/

Comment: still same error....
I added "cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);" excatly after sql="..."

Comment: Done everything like in here - but still I have problems with that iD_User

Comment: Go back to the syntax for AddWithValue

Comment: The syntax `Add(string, SqlDbType, int32)` means add a parameter with name, type and SIZE, NOT VALUE.

Comment: did already - but still no good...

"cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iD_User", IDD);"

Comment: Thanks, but with "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iD_User", IDD);" still I have problems. :/ Like it doesn't like int inside variable...

Comment: And the error is still the same? _Must be declared scalar value "@iD_User_

Comment: And you should use ExecuteNonQuery to execute this command, not ExecuteScalar (also if I think that it is the same)

Comment: Yes error is same.
(and that ExecuteNonQuery didn't helped.)

Comment: OK, now it is the time to start the debugger, put a breakpoint on the line the define the sql text (F9) and the run your program (F5) until you hit the breakpoint, then proceed step by step (F10) looking at the actual values of your variables. (watch window, local window)

Comment: here is sql="insert into Action_Log (ID_User,Action_NR,AtWhatTime) values (@iD_User,@action_NR,getdate())"

Comment: and the cmd.Parameters collection contains all the parameters declared when your code reaches the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` line?

Comment: It does - I have no idea where is problem. :/

I will try one trick to be sure that int is not a problem (I will make +1-1) maybe like this it will work...

Comment: whatever I do - it does not work...

now I will define int manualy like IDD=15;

Comment: Check also the Action_Log table for the exact correspondence of column names.

Comment: Even with manualy defined IDD - it still makes the problem :/

Still except scalar value :/

Comment: I checked it (multiple times). - I can see it on side - but still error.

Comment: Now I changed to: "sql = "insert into Action_Log ([ID_User],[Action_NR],[AtWhatTime]) values (@iDUser,@action_NR,getdate())";" still same problem :/ wtf?

Comment: Try removing the parameter and passing a constant in the sql text `values(15,@action_NR....)`

Comment: I found the mistake - I had wroted "cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);" after parsing the variables - not before.... Now everything works (I will check in database - did the time had been wrote correct)

Answer (score 2):

Your statement `cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);` should come before adding parameters to the command.

Since you are using a single object `cmd` to execute both commands, it is adding parameters to previous reference and later when you initialize it again using `new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con)` your parameters are lost.

```
sql = "insert into Action_Log (ID_User,Action_NR,AtWhatTime) values (@iD_User,@action_NR,@atWhatTime)";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iD_User",SqlDbType.Int, IDD); //I had also tried: "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iD_User", IDD)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action_NR", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atWhatTime",DateTime.Now);
// Either pass `getdate` in your string query or send `DateTime.Now` as parameter. 
//Note that DateTime.Now could result in a different value than getdate. 
//Thanks to @Steve answer
```

Consider using parameters with your first command as well, otherwise your code is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also consider enclosing your command and connection object in [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) statement, that will ensure the disposal of resources.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your `cmd` before you try to add your parameters. Move this line before your parameter lines.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Sel_Menu.con);
```

And [`SqlParameterCollection.Add(String, SqlDbType, Int32)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes `size` as a third parameter not `value`. You might need to use [other overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

By the way, use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and commands.